# Using CakePHP helpers with TwigView plug-in not working

Tags: twig, helper, template-engine, cakephp-2.4

I've installed TwigView inside my `CakePHP` application and I'm trying loading the elements `header.twig.tpl` and `footer.twig.tpl` inside the default template called `default.twig.tpl`.

It works fine with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Hello world!</title>

</head>
<body>
{% element 'header.twig' %}

    {{ test_var_from_controller }} <!-- this works and echoes "Hello world!" as expected -->

{% element 'footer.twig' %}
</body>
</html>
```

The problem starts when I try to use `CakePHP` default `Helpers`, they are simply ignored.

I'm not sure why, if I try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Hello world!</title>
    {{ html.css('styes.min') }}
</head>
```

The method is ignored without throw errors and the page still working like it was never called.

I've followed all the **[TwigView explanation](https://github.com/predominant/TwigView)** but it still not working, what I'm missing?

I'm also trying using Twig functions and they seems to be not loaded for some reason:

```
{{ 'FOO'|low }}
```

Throws the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function low() in .../app/Plugin/TwigView/tmp/views/2d/4b/65accc...92.php on line 45
```

Comment: as I said I don't get errors, they are simply ignored.

Comment: I also found that the `dump` method `{{ dump(some_var) }}` is not found by twig, and throws an error: `The function "dump" does not exist in "Layouts/default.twig.tpl" at line 22`

Comment: I also having Problem with Load twig to cakephp can you tell me how to load the plugin Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem, i needed to load the Helpers inside AppController first

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $viewClass = 'TwigView.Twig';
    public $ext = '.twig.tpl';
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3, if you are using the WyriHaximus plugin, you can put this in src/View/AppView.php

```
namespace App\View;
use WyriHaximus\TwigView\View\TwigView;

/**
 * Application View
 */
class AppView extends TwigView
{
  /**
   * Initialization hook method.
   * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading helpers.
   * e.g. `$this->loadHelper('Html');`
   * @return void
   */
  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadHelper('Html');
    $this->loadHelper('Flash');
    $this->loadHelper('Url');
    ...
  }
}
```